# Use RVM to point to custom Ruby path

Tags: centos, ruby, rvm

I have my ruby-2.3.1 installed in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby`, but by some problems with dependencies KDE downloads ruby-2.1 to `/usr/bin/ruby` and now my system uses that version.

I've install RVM in the hope I could use that to change the path from `/usr/bin/ruby` to `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby` so I'm using that version again.

But I can't see if that's possible. Anyone got some tips?

Answer (score 0):

The safest thing to do is to remove the manually installed ruby in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby` and install ruby 2.3.1 with

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

but you can also add the existing ruby 2.3.1 with

```
rvm mount /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
```